# What is 'object_table' and 'object_id' in Acl API?

Tags: api, acl

I am not understanding the meaning of 'object_role' and 'object_id' in ACL API. I was trying to manage ACL using CiviCRM API 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object table is the type of data the ACL is operating on.

For eg: if you want to create an ACL which grants permission for an event - object table, in this case, will be `civicrm_event`.

Object id is the id of the event to which the permission is applied to. An example of API which uses these two params could be -

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Acl', 'create', [
  'object_table' => "civicrm_event",
  'object_id' => 2, //event id, 0 for all events.
]);
```

Comment: What is the use of  "civicrm_saved_search" table? Because I want to give permission for one role to other groups ( View permission) using CiviCRM API.

Comment: `civicrm_saved_search` table is used to store details of the smart groups created in civicrm. To give permission for a SG, i think you can directly use civicrm_group for `object table` and id of the smart group in `object_id` param.